# How do I redirect before function can be called?

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies

I have created a site that counts the number of times a user has visited by creating a cookie with a +1 counter on it. After every fifth visit it asks the user to register. Once the user has register, it deletes the cookie and replaces it with the registration information (it is for school, or I would never be doing it like this). After the new cookie is created it redirects to a new page that displays that information from the cookie. Then if the user visits the site again, it is supposed to redirect before the counter can start, using the same criteria as the first redirect. That is not working. It creates the counter cookie anyway without redirecting.

The code I am using is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>

        </title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">

/////// Variable "name" is what gives the cookie its name. ///////
    var name = "cookie";
        function redirect() {
var x = document.forms.reg.first.value;
var y = document.forms.reg.last.value;  
        if (document.cookie == "Name: " + x + " Email: " + y) {
            window.location="registered.html";
            }
            else {
                setCookie();
            }
        }
/////// This function will set the cookie if no cookie exists. ///////
//////// Then it will add the value of 1 to the cookie name. ////////   
    function setCookie() {

        if (document.cookie) {
            i = document.cookie.indexOf(name);
        }       
        else {
            i = -1;
        }
        if (i == -1) {
            document.cookie = name+ "=1; max-age=" +2592000;
        }    
        else {
            var start = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", i) + 1);
            var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", i); 
            if (end == -1) {
                end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            var count = eval(document.cookie.substring(start, end)) + 1;
            document.cookie = name+ "=" +count+ "; max-age=" + 2592000;
        var popup = count % 5;
        if (popup == 0) {
            alert("Please Register");
        }
        else {
            return
        }   
        }
        }

    function formCheck() {
    var x = document.forms.reg.first.value
    var y = document.forms.reg.last.value
        if (x =="") {
            alert("Something");
        return false;
        }
        if (y =="") {
            alert("Something Else");
        return false;   
        }
        else {
            document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
            document.cookie = "Name: " + x + " Email: " + y;
            alert(document.cookie);
        }
        if (document.cookie == "Name: " + x + " Email: " + y){
            window.location.replace("registered.html");
            return false;
        }
        }

        </script>       
    </head>
<body onload="redirect();">

<form name="reg" onSubmit="return(formCheck());">
Type your first name: <input type="text" name="first">
    <br>
Type your last name: <input type="text" name="last">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have come a long way from the last question I asked, and am almost proud of myself, but this is kicking my butt. It has taken me almost 20 hours just to get this far, and this is the last thing I need.

Thank you.

UPDATE!

I was able to get it to work using this work arounf for redirect()

```
function redirect() {
    if (document.cookie.length > 15) {
        window.location.replace("registered.html");
    }
    else {
        setCookie();
    }
    }
```

Comment: So, from what I have been able to gather there reason the redirect is not working on visit, is because it relies on the cookie having the values of x,y where as those not longer exist.

So, if they no longer have the value of document.form...." then what is another way to redirect on visit if new cookie exists?

Comment: What is the code you have on registered.html?

Comment: Just a function tied to body onload that write out the value of the cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having trouble following your function calls so I started from scratch, I believe this does what you want. Please review it and modify your code accordingly instead of using this as your final code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>            
        function updateVisits(){
            var num_visits = getCookie('visits');
            if( !num_visits ) {
                num_visits = 0;                   // first visit
            }
            num_visits++;                         // add 1
            setCookie ('visits', num_visits, 30); // create/update cookie
        }

        function checkVisits(){
            var nag_limit = 5; // nag on 5+ visits
            if(parseInt(getCookie('visits')) >= nag_limit) {
                alert('Please register');
            }
        }

        // Does user cookie exist?
        function isRegistered(){
            if(getCookie('user')) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }    
        }

        function registerUser()
        {
            var first = document.forms.reg.first.value;
            var last = document.forms.reg.last.value;

            if(first == ''){
                alert('Please enter first name');
            } else if(last == '') {
                alert('Please enter last name');
            } else { // everything checked out
                var cookie_value = first + ' ' + last;
                setCookie('user', cookie_value, 30); // save user cookie
                window.location = 'registered.html';
            }
            return false;
        }

        function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
        {
            var exdate=new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value=escape(value) +
                    ((exdays==null) ? "" : ("; expires="+exdate.toUTCString()));
            document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }

        function getCookie(c_name)
        {
            var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
            for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
                x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
                y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
                x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
                if (x==c_name) {
                    return unescape(y);
                }
            }
        }

        // Run every page load
        window.onload = function(){
            var registered = isRegistered();  // check if already registered, then redirect
            if(registered) {
                window.location = 'registered.html'; // user already registered
            } else {
                updateVisits();     // set/update cookie
                checkVisits();      // nag user if needed
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="reg" onSubmit="return(registerUser());">
    First name: <input type="text" name="first"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="last">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I very much appreciate it. I already turned in my assignment with what I had, but I think this will come in handy to at least see where I could have cleaned things up, or made them run smoother. 
I have a hard time understanding people code though, as I am so new to JavaScript. So it will take me a while, and a bit of Googling to understand fully, what everything does. 

Thank you again.